# Pandastable transpose columns so they are vertical

Tags: python, pandas, transpose, pandastable

i am using pandastable to display pandas dataframes in a tkinter GUI. I have one dataframe that only has one row and three columns so I want to display it vertically to save space in my GUI.
The original table is something like:

```
Max  | Min  | Average
25.2 | 1.24 | 17.89
```

And I want it to ultimately look like:

```
Max     | 25.2
Min     | 1.24
Average | 17.89
```

I've tried to transpose the dataframes before creating the pandastable and transpose the pandastable Table object but neither works. I get this error when trying to do:

```
agg_pt = Table(dataframe=agg_df)
agg_pt.transpose()

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

Because transpose is applicable for dataframe. The agg_pt is not an dataframe type. you can transpose the dataframe and after convert to table like this

```
agg_pt = Table(dataframe=agg_df.transpose())
```

I hope this will work for you case